# Anti join but only return "previous" missing row

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(name = c(rep('Alice', 4), rep('Bob', 3)),
                timestamp = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 1, 3, 4), stringsAsFactors = F)

y <- 
    base::merge(I(c('Alice', 'Bob')), c(1:3, 5:15)) # note missing time stamp = 4
names(y) <- names(x)
y <-
    y %>%
    arrange(name,timestamp)
```

I would like to find, if it exists, the last row in each contiguous block (ordered using `timestamp`) in the data frame `anti_join(y,x)`.

Using the example data, construct the `anti_join`:

```
x_missing <-
    dplyr::anti_join(y, x) %>%
    arrange(name,timestamp)
```

which gives

```
> head(x_missing, 11)
    name timestamp
1  Alice         2
2  Alice         3
3  Alice         6
4  Alice         7
5  Alice         8
6  Alice         9
7  Alice        12
8  Alice        13
9  Alice        14
10 Alice        15
11   Bob         2
```

I would like the solution to be:

```
  name timestamp
  Alice         3
  Alice         9
  Alice        15
  ...
```

The solution needs to be faster than computing `anti_join(y,x)`, which is excessively slow when `x,y` are big.

Comment: the three contiguous timestamp blocks for Alice are (2,3), (6,7,8,9) and (12,13,14,15)

Comment: `y %>% anti_join(x) %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(!timestamp %in% (timestamp - 1)) %>% arrange(name, timestamp)`?

Comment: @alistaire you should put that in an answer, nice

Answer (score 2):

This improves the speed of the anti-join and uses a loop to get the rows you want, but there's certainly some better way to pick the rows than using my hack-ish loop.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(name = c(rep('Alice', 4), rep('Bob', 3)),
                timestamp = c(1, 5, 10, 11, 1, 3, 4), stringsAsFactors = F)

y <- 
  base::merge(I(c('Alice', 'Bob')), c(1:3, 5:15)) # note missing time stamp = 4
names(y) <- names(x)


y <-
  y %>%
  arrange(name,timestamp)

x$nt <- paste(x$name,x$timestamp)
y$nt <- paste(y$name,y$timestamp)

ynt <- y[!y$nt %in% x$nt,] # should be faster

tmp <- data.frame(name=NA,timestamp=NA)
for(i in 2:nrow(ynt)){
        if((ynt[i-1,2]+1) < (ynt[i,2])){tmp <- rbind(ynt[i-1,1:2],tmp)}
        if(!((ynt[i-1,1]) == (ynt[i,1]))){tmp <- rbind(ynt[i-1,1:2],tmp)}
        if(i == nrow(ynt)){tmp <- rbind(ynt[i,1:2],tmp)}
}

tmp <- tmp[order(tmp$name,tmp$timestamp),]; tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp$name),]
tmp

    name timestamp
   Alice         3
   Alice         9
   Alice        15
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to filter to the last row of an arithmetic sequence is to filter to rows that are in the sequence shifted back a term, i.e. minus its difference (here just 1). While this simplifies getting from A to B, it doesn't speed up `anti_join`, which is a bigger job unless you can leverage the patterns of your data.

```
y %>% anti_join(x) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(!timestamp %in% (timestamp - 1)) %>%   
  arrange(name, timestamp)

# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# Groups: name [2]
# 
#     name timestamp
#   (AsIs)     (int)
# 1  Alice         3
# 2  Alice         9
# 3  Alice        15
# 4    Bob         2
# 5    Bob        15
```

If you like, you can do the anti-join manually with `filter`, which while faster for the sample data, may scale poorly; `%in%` is not terribly efficient.

```
y %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(!timestamp %in% x[x$name == unique(name), 'timestamp']) %>% 
  filter(!timestamp %in% (timestamp - 1))
```

Or without `%in%`:

```
y %>% anti_join(x) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  arrange(timestamp) %>%
  filter(c(diff(timestamp), 0) != 1)
```

The results are identical.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` possibility. No idea about the relative speed:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
setDT(y)
keycols = c("name","timestamp")
setkeyv(x,keycols)
setkeyv(y,keycols)

y[!x][c(diff(timestamp)!= 1,TRUE)]

#    name timestamp
#1: Alice         3
#2: Alice         9
#3: Alice        15
#4:   Bob         2
#5:   Bob        15
```